# Do we need [space-construct] and [space-station]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

So I had fun with space-questions, and learned we have a [space-construct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-construct) and [space-station](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-station). It occurs to me that every spacestation is a space-construct. I can't immediatly immagine a spacestation that is not artificial, and as such I see [space-station](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-station) repetitive.

What do you think?

Comment: I created the tag but it seems the question tag has changed so it's no used anymore. But spaceships can also be construct. And Dyson sphere (yes we have a tag for this as well)

Comment: good point, I added a stationary somewhere in there in my mind...

Comment: I do think they are repetitive, but only after how the community has chosen to use them - i.e. they aren't necessarily redundant (although they're close). Incidentally, does anyone know why [tag:spacestation] isn't [tag:space-station]?

Comment: [tag:spacestation] is now [tag:space-station]

Comment: when i use the [space-station] tag it gets changed to [space-constructs]...?